# Jquery raty is theres a way to callback the cancel button?

Tags: jquery, rating-system, raty

Does anyone here who familiar with jquery raty?

is theres a way to callback the cancel button?

here's my code

```
$(".ratings").raty({
    cancel: function() {
        return $(this).attr("data-cancel");
    }
});
```

I want something like that. But my code seems not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the code from my example below. You see a callback function for the click event. Because it will be executed on all clicks, you have to find a way to only execute some code when the cancel button is clicked. In my example you see this check is done based on the class name of the clicked element.

```
$(".ratings").raty({
    cancel : true,
    click  : function(score, evt) {
        alert("Score: " + score);

        // This is one way to check if you clicked the cancel button.
        if(evt.currentTarget.className === "raty-cancel")
        {
            // At this point we know you clicked the cancel button,
            // so insert code here to execute on callback.
        }
    }
});
```

In the callback function the `alert("Score: " + score);` returns null, so when it reaches this method, the score has already been removed due to clicking the cancel button.

Comment: thank you sir but what I want to do is not to show the cancel button unless I put data-cancel="true" in my html tag which calls back the cancel to true